# When is it a good idea to use the Django template tag "with"?

Tags: django, django-templates

I understand that one of the biggest purpose of the [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#with) tag is to "cache a complex variable name" in a template.

But when is it a good idea to use it?

I'm assuming if I ever hit the database with `count()`, `all()`, `filter()`, or `get()` using the same template variable, then I should use `with`.

But what about for simple field lookups like `user.username`? In a particular template, I would be calling `user.username` many times.

Should I be using `with` for `user.username` or maybe even pass it a simple string from the view via a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason to use `with` for `user.username` is if you don't like typing the long name each time. There's almost no overhead in that lookup, so there's no point trying to cache it.

Even forward foreignkey and one-to-one relations, like `user.userprofile.name`, are cached automatically by the ORM the first time you use them, so there's little point using `with` for those either.

Comment: Really forward foreign keys? So doing something like `{% blog.comments.all %}` is cached? Why is the documentation example saying to cache `{% business.employees.count %}`? Isn't that a forward foreign key as well?

Comment: No, those are both reverse foreign keys, or many-to-many. A forward FK would be `comment.blog.title` or `employee.business.name`.

Comment: So M2M is never cached as well?

Comment: No. M2Ms and reverse FKs both create new querysets, which are not cached (unless you use the new 1.4 `prefetch_related` function).